# Vlookup does not see opened files c# - edit

Tags: c#, excel, excel-interop

I have these lines of code in a loop:

```
rfmSheet.Cells[i, 18].Formula = String.Format("=VLOOKUP(O{0},[POvsPT.xlsx]Sheet1!$H:$K,4,0)", i);
rfmSheet.Cells[i, 19].Formula = String.Format("=VLOOKUP(P{0},'[PT Vendor.xlsx]Sheet1'!$A:$C,3,0)", i);
```

Both files are in the same directory and I open them both prior to the execution of the loop.
The first vlookup formula does it's job perfectly but the second one gives a pop-up requesting that I should open the file, although it's already opened. What am I doing wrong here?

**EDIT**

So after doing more testing it seems that the first file got opened because somehow I saved a copy of it in Documents and it fetched it from there. After deleting it the open dialog appeared.

Is there a way to make the formula see that the file is already opened? I'm really stuck with this...

Comment: check extension of your second file. Is it really `xlsx` and also check spaces in file name

Comment: same extension as the first one and the spaces are also correct...as I previously tested the only time it didn't request for open was when I put the absolute path there